# Running a series of delegates with Parallel.Invoke containing calls to another appdomain

Tags: c#, multithreading, serialization, task-parallel-library, marshalling

Okay I'll try and keep this short :)

Essentially what I've got is an architecture that creates a new appdomain and loads plugin assemblies into it. This is so that plugin DLLs can be hot-swappable using Shadow Copy without bringing the service offline.

I've then got a dictionary containing references to those loaded plugins (really proxy objects generated by using MarshallByRef)

When work comes into the service it will generally require several of the plugins to process the workloads that are coming in. I want to spin up a new thread for each of the plugins and feed it the workload, so that work can be processed in parallel (I'm using TPL to achieve this)

```
List<Action> actions = new List<Action>();
foreach(var work as workitemgroup){
    actions.Add(delegate() {
        PluginManager.Dispatchers[work.workType.ToLower()].Execute(work.workload); 
    });
}
Parallel.Invoke(actions.ToArray());
```

The problem is this (namespace names changed to protect the innocent ;)

> Type 'System.Linq.Lookup`2+Grouping[[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[App.Model.Work.Workload, App.Model, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]' in Assembly 'System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' is not marked as serializable.

strangely if I change the delegate to something like:

```
actions.Add(delegate() { Console.WriteLine("test"); }
```

...it works fine, but my question is this - what requires serialization in this case?
AFAIK the delegate shouldn't need to be serialized and sent to the other AppDomain - it should be executing here and then the call to the proxy would require serialization of the workload model (which is marked as serializable anyway).

Comment: I think this doesn't have anything to do with `Parallel.Invoke`. Have you tried invoking the delegate without it? Your issue is with marshaling across the `AppDomain` boundary, so it's no surprise that if you don't do that, your code works. Also, it's hard to see what's going on with this little code. It would really help if you created a small, but complete sample that shows your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can only guess that you use some objects created locally in the action delegates you pass to the remote plugins and these objects are not serializable. With Console.Writeline you dont pass any nonserializable object to the plugin that's why it works.

Answer (score 1):

Found it -

work.workload was the result of a LINQ expression which couldn't be serialized - casting it to an array with work.workload.ToArray() was enough to win the day